# Creating a for loop for finding and terminating roles from an array in discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, discord, discord.js

When I use a command .red It gives the perp a role from the array of role IDs namely xarr here, now I would like to get it's values to create a for loop to check through the IDs and remove the role so that only one role remains with the user.

My main aim is to do get a bot with a command .x giving role x and then command .y giving a role y removing x and other from the user and simultaneously doing this for other commands .z, role z and other vars respectively

This is what I have come up with this far

```js
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
    const xarr = ["774301199067250738","826413888157384724"];
            if(message.content.startsWith("test")){
                message.reply('test')
            }
           
if(message.content.startsWith(".red")){

    try {
    message.member.roles.add(xarr[0])
    for( let x;
        x < message.member.roles.cache.size;
         x++ ) {
             console.log(xarr[x])
            if (message.member.roles.cache.has(xarr[x])) { message.member.roles.remove(xarr[x])
            }
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        message.reply(e)

    }

} else { 
    if(message.content.startsWith(".p")){

message.member.roles.add(xarr[1])
for( let x;
    x < message.member.roles.cache.size;
     x++ ) {
         console.log(xarr[x])
        if (message.member.roles.cache.has(xarr[x])) { message.member.roles.remove(xarr[x])
        }
    }
    }
    }
}
)
```

I can not find out how to create a proper for loop for such a case.

Is there any other method to achieve my goal?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to loop through all the users that have role x and remove the role from them. Is this right?

Comment: I want to remove role x and assign y and then assign z removing y and so on , considering that we can do it through command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I believe I understand what you're saying.

If I understood it well, you want to create a command that add a role to a member and removes a different role of your choice from him.

If that's so, we could simply create a function that takes in two parameters (call them `x` and `y` for example), and we could simply add and remove those roles.

```js
const addAndRemoveRoles = (x /* the role we'd like to add */, y /* the role we'd like to remove */) => {
  const { member } = message
  if (!member.roles.cache.has(x)) member.roles.add(x)
  if (members.roles.cache.has(y)) member.roles.remove(y)
}

// Testing this with the command '.x' that would give the member the x role and remove the y role
if (message.content.startsWith('.x') {
  const xRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('...')
  const yRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('...')
  addAndRemoveRoles(xRole, yRole) // Calling our function with the roles
}
```

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to achieve something similar **although** I would like to use it with multiple ones for example: roles x,y and z and let's say more to be a b c the user must have only one role after the command that is specified within it how would the function work in such a case?

Comment: In that case you'd probably want to accept an array of role ID's as your parameter, and create a `.forEach()` iterator to go through them and execute what you'd like to do with each one of the ID's.